# Nautilus scripts not showing up (although on the right folder and executable)

Tags: scripts, nautilus

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 and I'm setting everything up. 
I wanted to add a couple of scripts to the right click menu. Putted them on ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts .
Made them executable.
Reboot.
(so far what most answers about nautilus scripts not showing up say)

Right click on any folder or file or anything and the scripts option still doesn't appear.

Maybe I didn't install a required package? what am I missing?

Last but not least, thank you for your help. This is my first question in this forum but it has rescued me many times.

Comment: Could you post (any of the) script(s)

Comment: Hyperspy notebook here.sh

#!/bin/sh
# hyperspy-here
ipython notebook --profile "hyperspy"